# Algorithm to connect all dots with the minimum total distance

Tags: algorithm

I have a set of points and a distance function applicable to each pair of points. I would like to connect ALL the points together, with the minimum total distance. Do you know about an existing algorithm I could use for that ?

Each point can be linked to several points, so this is not the usual "salesman itinerary" problem :)

Thanks !

Comment: This could be interpreted as a minimum-weight spanning tree problem. I'm not sure that's the best way to approach it but it's one way.

Comment: If the distance metric follows D(x,z) <= D(x,y) + D(y,z) for every three points x,y&z then basically connecting every pair points would give total minimum distance. I think you need to refine your question a bit.

Comment: The distance metric could be the sum of all connections' lengths.

Comment: Sorry guys my formulation of the question was not very clear. You're right @biziclop, this is a minimum-weight spanning tree problem. I didn't know this term.

Comment: @Blacksad Sometimes all we need is the name of the concept we're after. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you want is a [Minimum spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree).

The two most common algorithms to generate one are:

- [Prim's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm)
- [Kruskal's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm)

Answer (score 7):

As others have said, the [minimum spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) (MST) will allow you to form a minimum distance sub-graph that connects all of your points.

You will first need to form a graph for your data set though. To efficiently form an undirected graph you could compute the [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) of your point set. The conversion from the triangulation to the graph is then fairly literal - any edge in the triangulation is also an edge in the graph, weighted by the length of the triangulation edge.

There are efficient algorithms for both the MST (Prim's/Kruskal's `O(E*log(V))`) and Delaunay triangulation (Divide and Conquer `O(V*log(V))`) phases, so efficient overall approaches are possible.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm you are looking for is called minimum spanning tree. It's useful to find the minimum cost for a water, telephone or electricity grid. There is Prim's algorithm or Kruskal algorithm. IMO Prim's algorithm is a bit easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree you can find more information about the minimum spanning tree, so you can adapt it to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Dijkstra's algorithm:

Dijkstra's algorithm, conceived by Dutch computer scientist Edsger Dijkstra in 1956 and published in 1959, is a graph search algorithm that solves the single-source shortest path problem for a graph with nonnegative edge path costs, producing a shortest path tree. This algorithm is often used in routing and as a subroutine in other graph algorithms.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm