# Given a set of cartesian points, find the shortest total-length network that connects all points together

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

(Just for the sake of transparency, I want to mention right off the bat that this is a homework problem).

I have a set of (x, y) points including a specific starting point. I want to find the network of shortest overall length such that every point is reachable from the starting point.

I know that this mirrors a MST in a graph, but the problem is that the points aren't arranged in a graph, but rather are unconnected. I know that I could find a valid MST by connecting every point to every other point and running Prim-Jarnik, but in this case, just creating the graph would be O(n^2) for the number of points in the set, right?

I have found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471043/algorithm-to-connect-all-dots-with-the-minimum-total-distance), but it recommends using something called Delaunay triangulation to create a graph from the points and then running Prim-Jarnik on it. I'm pretty sure that's beyond the scope of what my course expects of me given that it's an intro algos/data structures course and that this was never mentioned.

Is there a more efficient way to find the solution than creating a graph in n^2 time and then running Prim-Jarnik (without advanced geometry), or is that the best we can do?

Comment: It's okay to ask homework questions here, *but* Stack Overflow is for specific programming problems; I'm not sure if this is the right Stack Exchange site...?

Comment: Just look  at limits for maximum number of points, if n < 5001, doing classical Kruskal or  Prim for all  n^2 edges  is good enough, otherwise you do need Delaunay triangulation.